# Find exact matching values based on other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to check Column title and find all exact matching values from other Columns (attributes) and give an output.

[image: more details in the image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your screenshot and desired output are difficult to understand. Do you just want to filter your data? Unfortunately, I'm not sure your data is structured in a way to allow easy filtering.

Comment: Your screenshot can not clearly express the problem, please re-upload the screenshot, the exact search can be Ctrl+F to bring up the find dialog, check to match  entire cell content.

Comment: please hold this as I am working on testing a solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the title is in cell B2, and that the list of valid colors is in the defined range `color`, and that you'll only ever have one match per attribute, you could do something like

```
=INDEX(color,MATCH(1,SEARCH(color,B2),-1))
```

SEARCH() will return an array with the starting position of the string in each element of `color` within the string in B2, so if "Brown" is the 3rd row in `color`, it'll be {#VALUE, #VALUE, 16, #VALUE...}.

MATCH() will return the position of the search term that is >=1, i.e. the element of `color` that was found within B2, in this case 3. This argument will be passed to the index function, returning the color.